# How can I reset primeng datatable sort state?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'd like to reset the sort state of primeng datable. i am able to reset full datatable but still sort state is not reset

Comment: There's a method `reset()` which resets sort, filter and paginator state: http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable

Comment: yes it is reseting but css and color is not reseted by this

Comment: what is "sort state"? can you please attach a screenshot?

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

HTML

```
<p-table #table ...>
```

TS

```
import {Table} from 'primeng/table';

@ViewChild('table') table: Table;

resetSort() {
 this.table.sortOrder = 0;
 this.table.sortField = '';
 this.table.reset();
}
```

Comment: I was unable to get this to work, however when i put the default sort field in it worked. `this.table.sortField = '';` changed to `this.table.sortField = 'myDefaultSortColumnName';` and changed .sortOrder to 1.